# Java Swing GUI- adding a single border at the bottom

Tags: java, swing

I want to add a single border at the bottom of my window and I have tried it using the `MatteBorder` but the border is being extended only up to the panel which consists of my `GridBagLayout`.(as shown in the picture). I know this is because I have set the border to that panel but the border is not even appearing when I am adding it to a new sub panel and then adding that panel to the main panel and ultimately the main panel to the `JFrame`.
I want the border to extend all along the bottom of the window.

Here is my code:

```
public class Admin_hs extends JFrame {

    JButton bking_btn= new JButton("Bookings");
    JButton fd_btn= new JButton("Financial Data");
    JButton ctm_btn= new JButton("Customers");
    JButton room_btn= new JButton("Rooms");
    JButton adc_btn= new JButton("Additional Costs");
    JButton endb_btn= new JButton("Ending Bookings");

    //Images
    JLabel bking_img= new JLabel();
    JLabel fd_img= new JLabel();
    JLabel ctm_img= new JLabel();
    JLabel room_img= new JLabel();
    JLabel adc_img= new JLabel();
    JLabel endb_img= new JLabel();

    ///Panels

    JPanel pnl1= new JPanel();
    JPanel pnl= new JPanel();

    ///Constructors

    public Admin_hs(){
        this.setTitle("Welcome Admin!");
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        ///Setting a layout


        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth= GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gbc.fill= gbc.HORIZONTAL;

        pnl.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gc= new GridBagConstraints();

        ///First Column of Grid


        gc.insets = new Insets(6, 6, 6, 6);
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gc.weightx = 0.5;
        gc.weighty = 0.5;

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 0;

        pnl.add(bking_btn, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        pnl.add(fd_btn, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 2;
        pnl.add(ctm_btn, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 3;
        pnl.add(room_btn, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 4;
        pnl.add(adc_btn, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 5;
        pnl.add(endb_btn, gc);


        /////second column of grid



        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        bking_img.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Diksha/Desktop/OOSD Assignment/icons/60-60/booking.jpg"));
        pnl.add(bking_img, gc);

        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        fd_img.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Diksha/Desktop/OOSD Assignment/icons/60-60/fd.jpg"));
        pnl.add(fd_img, gc);

        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 2;
        ctm_img.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Diksha/Desktop/OOSD Assignment/icons/60-60/guest.jpg"));
        pnl.add(ctm_img, gc);

        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 3;
        room_img.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Diksha/Desktop/OOSD Assignment/icons/60-60/room.jpg"));
        pnl.add(room_img, gc);

        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 4;
        adc_img.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Diksha/Desktop/OOSD Assignment/icons/60-60/adc.jpg"));
        pnl.add(adc_img, gc);

        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 5;
        endb_img.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Diksha/Desktop/OOSD Assignment/icons/60-60/endb.png"));
        pnl.add(endb_img, gc);

        pnl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 2, 0, Color.BLACK));

        this.add(pnl);



    }

}
```

**Main**

```
public class Admin_main {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Admin_hs adm= new Admin_hs();

    adm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    adm.pack();
    adm.setVisible(true);
    adm.setSize(780,520);

    }

}
```

Currently it looks like this:
[image]

I want the window to look like this(this was done using Windows Paint):

[image]

Comment: You didn't provide any of the images for us to test with.  You also need to bring the images inside your Java project, so that you can export them in your JAR file.

Comment: I can't test it now, but you can add a `BorderLayout` to your frame and set `pnl` at `CENTER` position, then create an empty `JPanel`, add an upper border to it and set it to `SOUTH` position. Or, you could look into `WebLAF` which has a `WebStatusBar` component that should work exactly for what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You draw a `MatteBorder` at the Bottom of your `JPanel pnl` and it is not as long as the window width, because your `JPanel pnl` is not as long as the window width as you can see here.
[image]

So you already defined another `JPanel pnl1` but you did not use it.

```
public Admin_hs(){
    this.setTitle("Welcome Admin!");
    this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        ///Setting a layout
    pnl1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());   // ADD THIS LINE
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridwidth= GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    gbc.fill= GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.weightx = 1;                       // ADD THIS LINE so it uses all the existing window size in x direction
    pnl1.add(pnl);                         // ADD THIS LINE
    [...]
    // CHANGE THIS LINE to use the bottom border of your pnl1
    pnl1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 2, 0, Color.BLACK));
    this.add(pnl1,gbc);                    // CHANGE THIS LINE to add pnl1 and not pnl to your main window
}
```

and you will get this 
[image]

Comment: Can you explain to me what  `gbc.gridwidth= GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;`
    `gbc.fill= GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;`
    `gbc.weightx = 1;` do? I am new to Layouts so getting some difficulty understanding GridBagLayout

Comment: You should study the GridBagConstraints [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html) and [Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). In short: 'gridwidth=REMAINDER' (Number of cells in one row, REMAINDER->the only component is the last), 'fill=HORIZONTAL' (howto fill space if larger then needed: NO, VERT, HORIZ, BOTH), 'weightx=1' (the only component gets 100% of horizontal existing space)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was very helpful.